# Putting 2 Boolean controllers in a do while expression?

Tags: java, while-loop, do-while, controllers

newbie programmer here.  I'm using Java to try and create a number guessing game.  I want my do while loop to continue looping until the user inputs the correct number OR they run out of guesses.  This is what I have and I can't figure out how to use 2 boolean controllers for the life of me.

```
do
    {System.out.println("Enter guess #1");
    userGuess = keyboard.nextInt();

    } while ((userGuess != actualNumber) || (remainingGuesses = guesses;       remainingGuesses >= 1; remainingGuesses--));
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Seems like a for-loop will be more suitable.

Answer (score 2):

I think that you want something closer to this effect:

```
remainingGuess = guesses;
do {
   System.out.println("Enter guess #1");
   userGuess = keyboard.nextInt();
} while ( userGuess != actualNumber || remainingGuesses-- > 0 )
```

Line by line:

```
remainingGuesses = guesses;
```

assigns `guesses` to `remainingGuesses` *once*, if you were to do it every iteration of your loop, it would never end

```
userGuess != actualNumber || remainingGuesses-- > 0
```

Keep iterating while the user has guessed incorrectly *OR* `remainingGuesses` is more than `0`.

```
remainingGuesses--
```

Evaluates to the current value of the variable `remainingGuesses`, then after the expression decrements it by 1.

Comment: Doesn't `--remainingGuesses` make more sense?

Comment: You could really do it either way, I just picked one. It will still be decremented the next iteration of the loop.

Comment: a good answer I'd say, only concern I have is that it's probably good to establish the habit of breaking these types of things into seperate methods early (given the self professed newbie status).  Put an answer up based off of yours to demonstrate this.

Answer (score 0):

Initialize remaining guesses before entering the loop. Only check the condition in the while paranthesis "()"

```
reaminingGuesses = guesses;
do
    {System.out.println("Enter guess #1");
    userGuess = keyboard.nextInt();
    remainingGuess--;
    } while ((userGuess != actualNumber) || (remainingGuesses >= 1));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want it as a do while I would make a few minor changes, and assuming you have constants defined for things like actualNumber and the total number of allowed guesses:

```
// break the calls into seperate methods, to make them easier to read in the long term and to 
// seperate logical concerns into discrete elements.
do {
//  get the user guess
   guess = getGuess();
// if shouldStop returns true you would stop, if it returns false you should continue, thus the !..
}  while (!shouldStop(guess)) {
   // decrement the guesses.
   --remainingGuesses;
}

///  define these methods somewhere..,
// get your guess
public int getGuess() {
   System.out.println("Enter guess #1");
   return keyboard.nextInt();
}


public boolean shouldStop(int guess) {
// condensed if statement syntax in java, very handy for this kind of thing
    // do we have enough remaining guess to keep going?  If so, compare the guess to the actual number
   // otherwise return true (the stop signal
   return remainingGuesses > 0 ? guess == actualNumber : true;
}
```

If you really wanted to follow the whole thing through you could break the guess==actual number into a method as well, but its probably not needed in this case since its a simple equality check.

The methos `shouldStop` could be defined a number of ways however...

Early on I think it's helpful to write these logical blocks out fully, and condense from there, for example:

```
public boolean shouldStop(int guess) {
  if(remainingGuesses <=0) {
     return true;
  }  else if(guess == actualNumber) {
     return true;
  }  else {
     return false;
}
```

}